# Google Analytics: Fraction of sessions in which a particular event occurred?

Tags: google-analytics

Suppose I have an event, say the "loading" category, that indicates when the users on my site are experiencing long load times.

I want to study the fraction of sessions in which the event occurs: for example, to determine which times of the week are most prone to the event, or whether there are significant jumps after new server deployments.

I can currently plot the *number* of sessions with the event, but this data is skewed because my traffic highly depends on the time of day and week.

There are many options for event analysis in Google Analytics.  Is there one that returns the *fraction* of total sessions in which a given event occurs?

Answer (score 1):

Do it creating the segment for sessions with that event.

1) add a new segment

2) in conditions tab: choose event action (ga:eventAction) which you want to track

3) save it & apply on traffic report

Result is a number of sessions with that event triggered, notice that you can create a segment for users also.

Comment: Hi, as stated in the question, I don't want the *number* of sessions, I want the *fraction* of sessions.  The number of visitors to my site varies greatly from day to day, and seeing the *number* of sessions in which a particular event occurred is not as helpful as the *fraction*.